# rails one search field handled by two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app I want to set a search form with two buttons. Each one of those buttons should send request to separate controller. Something like this:

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, method: :get) do %>
  Search Field <%= text_field_tag :q %>
  <br>
  <%= submit_tag 'First controller' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Second Controller' %>
<% end %>
```

Is this even possible? Or rails just impose on developer an "one form - one controller" way?

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why you want this scenario first place.

Comment: As @VishalTajPM said, I can't really see a use case for having two buttons for the same form in order to search 2 separate tables. Either have two seperate search forms or look into implementing global search.

Comment: I think from the UX perspective it is much more convenient to use one search bar instead of two separated onces. Since I want to browse the same model records but with different status field.

Comment: @andrzej541 then i would suggest you to update the question with form view for better understanding. in both case we cannot have 2 actions in one form and please explain this `status field` also.

Comment: Do it in JavaScript or have one controller search different things depending on which button was pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript to change the form URL based on the button clicked.

```
<%= form_tag(first_controller_path,id: 'search-form', method: :get) do %>
  Search Field <%= text_field_tag :q %>
  <br>
  <button type='submit' id="form-submit-button">First Controller</button>
  <button type='button' id="second-controller-button">Second Controller</button>
<% end %> 

<script>
$(function(){
   $("#second-controller-button").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = document.getElementById('search-form');
      form.action = '<%= second_controller_path %>' ;
      form.submit(); // Or you could also try document.getElementById("form-submit-button").click();
   })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 added some attributes to INPUT and BUTTON elements. One of them is `formaction` so you can set the action triggered by each button independantly and it overrides the default form action.

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, method: :get) do %>
  Search Field <%= text_field_tag :q %>
  <br>
  <%= submit_tag 'First controller' #triggers the default action %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Second Controller', formaction: another_path %>
<% end %>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp

Comment: This answer would be better if you used a reputable source like MDN instead of the clickbait w3schools.

Comment: @arieljuod This is a better solution than mine. I didn't know this :)

Answer (score 1):

You already defined `form_tag` with `products_path` through which the controller method is already defined.
So answering your question, you can't pass send requests to two different controllers with one `form`. 
If you want to pass some status with buttons try adding some attributes to the buttons and differentiate them inside the controller.

Comment: You need to understand one thing here, The OP didn't want to submit the form to 2 different actions simultaneously. Based on the button clicked he wanted to change the action which is pretty much possible with the help of JS.

Comment: @AbhilashReddy You are right. Then your answer seems convincing. Great!